# Transform matrix via rotation of values

Tags: python, matrix

How would you go about transofrming the values of a matrix from

```
A=
[0, 1, 2]
[-1, 0, 1]
[-2, -1, 0]
```

To this:

```
[0, -1, -2]
[1, 0, -1]
[2, 1, 0]
```

The operation is a mirror over the y=-x axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `numpy`, do `.T`:

```
>>> A = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
[-1, 0, 1],
[-2, -1, 0]])
>>> A.T
array([[ 0, -1, -2],
       [ 1,  0, -1],
       [ 2,  1,  0]])
>>>
```

In regular python, do `zip`:

```
>>> A = [[0, 1, 2],
[-1, 0, 1],
[-2, -1, 0]]
>>> list(zip(*A))
[(0, -1, -2), (1, 0, -1), (2, 1, 0)]
>>>
```

Comment: This is the only solution that seems to work and does so with minimal overhead. Thanks for the help!